# jQuery multiple products variants dropdown

Tags: jquery, json, product, dropdown

I have the following

```
<label>Model</label>
<select name="option1" id="option1">
    <option data-sku="IPH4-RED-ASD" value="iPhone4">iPhone4</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH5-GREEN-QWE" value="iPhone5">iPhone5</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH5-BLUE-QWE" value="iPhone5">iPhone5</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH5-ORANGE-QWE" value="iPhone5">iPhone5</option>
</select>

<label>Color</label>
<select name="option2" id="option2">
    <option data-sku="IPH4-RED-ASD" value="Red">Red</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH5-GREEN-QWE" value="Green">Green</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH6-BLUE-ZXC" value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH5-ORANGE-QWE" value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<label>Brand</label>
<select name="option3" id="option3">
    <option data-sku="IPH4-RED-ASD" value="ASD">ASD</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH5-GREEN-QWE" value="QWE">QWE</option>
    <option data-sku="IPH5-BLUE-ZXC" value="ZXC">ZXC</option>
</select>
```

As you can see iPhone5 shows up 3 times in the model dropdown since it comes with in 2 different colors which makes it as 2 individual products with unique SKUs.

I have the functionality in place when user selects iPhone4 it will show other variants if it has any.

Then problem is that I don't want to show iPhone5 3 times in the dropdown but only once. I know I can remove the duplicate from the JSON Array or remove the option from the dom but I need to keep the sku from which I get details if the variant is in stock or if it has a different price.

Shopify and Woocommerce are having same functionality except the fact that the result's don't repeat, any ideas/suggestions of what I can do?

I use jquery to print the selects and loop through variants in JSON format.

Thank you

Comment: Remove that from JSON and show only once in `option1 ` and I think you get the SKU from `option2` dropdown as well after user selection!

Comment: You could check if the option exists, if yes dont add it to your select box ;)

Comment: @theblackgigant if I don't add it to the select box then I won't know if iphone5 has a red color and a brand choice or if iphone5 red is out of stock and so on ...

Comment: @lesandru Well you could also check if it exists if yes, hide the element. So its available in your selectbox but users cant choose the option and you have your data

Comment: @theblackgigant the problem with you suggestions is that I show option2 based on the sku of option1, and option3 based on option1 and option2. If I hide the 2 duplicates of iPhone5 I don't get the colors in option2 that are related to those 2 hidden, just from other options. So probably I'm doing something wrong in the way I show the variants?

Answer (score 0):

If am getting your question right then, Option A is that
use substring method and match the data-sku va;ues and get the IPH5 string and show only one.

Option B is that give disabled tag so that the user cannot select the second and third iphone but can see that it's there.

Comment: you've got the question right except the fact that I hide the option2 if option1 doesn't have other variants, and option3 if either option1 or option2 don't have other variants related to them

Comment: ok, then you may please trim the json you get and group them. or give disabled for repeated ones. can you show me the website you told its working? any links?